# How make C++ Builder 2010 just install the professional edition where once an Architect edition

Tags: delphi, licensing, installation, delphi-2010, c++builder

In the computer, there is an C++ Builder 6 and was an C++ Builder Architect (the license isn't owned by the company) which was uninstalled.

I received the mission to install C++ Builder Professional 2010 recently bought on that machine, but the installer of the ISO (downloaded from Embarcadero) insists on installing the Architect edition and using the OLD license key - therefore not allowing the product to be activated.

Have anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I ended removing the uninstall leftover folders on:

1. \Program Files\Embarcadero\Rad Studio\7.0
2. \Documents and Settings\All Users\Local settings\Application Data\Embarcadero
3. \Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Embarcadero

Thus forcing the hellish installer to completely rebuild both.
Also, I kicked all the `{<guid>}` and `~<number>`  folders on the \Application Data\ folder before the install just to ensure it'll have to do all the job entirely. (Got a lot of space freed too ;-)).

Since I got the result on the run with ProcessMonitor, I don't know **EXACTLY** what is the hellish file - though I highly suspect of the one RadStudio2010.slip on the (1)\License directory, since that file has nothing to be there after an uninstall AND because I already deleted (2) on previous attempts.

[rant] ***In the installer gui would be nice to have a 'Reinstall all that thing killing every #&$@#$$@#$% survivor of the last uninstall in your path' button for those cases......*** [/rant]

Well, resuming the extreme approach:

1. Do the normal uninstall
2. Kill the Emba folder at \All Users\Application Data just to clean everything
   (I already had killed the whole folder on the failed attempts)
3. Kill all those `{<guid>}` and `~<number>` folders that the installer leave on the \All
   Users\Application Data
4. Kill the leftover Embarcadero\Rad Studio\7.0 folder on \Program Files\
5. Registry does not affect this problem *at all* ( I cleaned the registry ALL the times )
6. Now you can install.

Comment: Thanks to you Mason. I've spent long hours, before remember to check program files after seeing your answer......

Comment: I would like to mark Mason one too, since it's the spark that made me solve the question. Anyway, thank you very much Mason!!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem installing Delphi 2010.  It's caused by a bug in the installer leaving the previous registration file behind.  You have to find it and delete it.  I don't remember what it's called or where it's located.  I'd advise you to call Embarcadero tech support.  I got this fixed by talking to a very helpful guy there who explained the problem and pointed me to the right location.

Comment: Oh, has it been around for a while?

Comment: Since the installer is for a Update 4/5 ISO... I'll resort to Process Monitor to discover that undying file... And make sure it will be deleted! ;)

Comment: Again, call Embarcadero.  They can help you find where it is.

Comment: Note that Embarcadero provides **free support** for installation issues. I'm sure this would qualify, so don't hesitate to take advantage of it. (Then, after they tell you where the file is, come back here and post that as your own answer to this question.) http://support.embarcadero.com/forms/submitcase

Comment: Good point!  I probably should have mentioned that in the main answer.